# Default colors is not showing in fonts Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, fonts, emoji

Default Emojis are working fine in my Xamarin.Forms app and it's colorful. When I add [Twitter color fonts](https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font) its become B/W (black-white). This [Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts) I followed.

Initialization

```
[assembly: ExportFont( "TwitterColorEmoji.ttf", Alias = "TwitterColorEmoji" )]
```

Here is the example code in xaml

```
<!-- This is not working -->
<Label x:Name="emojilbl" Text="\U+1F1E9" Margin="20,0,0,0"></Label>
<Label 
    x:Name="emoji2lbl" 
    Text="&#x1F1E6;&#x1F1E8;" 
    Margin="20,0,0,0" 
    TextColor="#5EE514" 
    FontSize="40" 
    FontFamily="TwitterColorEmoji"></Label>

<!-- This is not working -->
<Image BackgroundColor="Black">
    <Image.Source>
        <FontImageSource 
            FontFamily="TwitterColorEmoji"
            Glyph="&#x1F1E6;&#x1F1E8;" 
            Size="40" 
            > 
        </FontImageSource>
    </Image.Source>
</Image> 

<!-- This is working fine with default font -->
<Label Text="&#x1F1E6;&#x1F1E8;"  Margin="20,0,0,0" FontSize="40"/>
```

[image]

Why emoji is not showing its own color.
Thank for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

### Solved issue by changing "Embedded resource" to "Resource" option.

[image]
[image]